# Need to add a comma between array items

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of words that gets shuffled into paragraphs using jQuery. I'm trying to add some commas "," in between them. Ideally i need a single comma added to every 4th word but this is beyond my modest jQuery skills.

This is my code:

```
    $("#generatebutt").click(function() {

    var dumpStr = "";

    var numberOfWords = $('#length').val();
    var numberpara = $('#numberpara').val();

    for (var i = 0; i < numberpara; i++) {
        Shuffle(melbArray);

        for (var j = 0; j < numberOfWords; j++) {
            var theWord = melbArray[j];
            dumpStr += theWord + " ";
        }

        dumpStr = dumpStr.trim();
        dumpStr += ".<br/><br/>";
    }

    $("#dump").html(dumpStr);

});
```

Really hope you can help!

Comment: if(j % 4 == 0) {
 // add comma
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#generatebutt").click(function() {

var dumpStr = "";

var numberOfWords = $('#length').val();
var numberpara = $('#numberpara').val();

for (var i = 0; i < numberpara; i++) {
    Shuffle(melbArray);

    for (var j = 0; j < numberOfWords; j++) {
        var theWord = melbArray[j];
        if(j % 4 == 0){
            dumpStr += theWord + ",";
        }
        else {
            dumpStr += theWord + " ";
        }
    }

    dumpStr = dumpStr.trim();
    dumpStr += ".<br/><br/>";
}

$("#dump").html(dumpStr);

});
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! This almost works perfectly for me but i have the array shuffled so what would have been the 4th item sometimes is the first making the paragraphs look unrealistic.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean. You wanna exclude the first item? if(j%4==0 && j!=0)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something done every *n* iterations then you should use the *modulo* `%` operator.

The `%` operator gives you the remainder of any division so for example `5 % 2` will be `1`.  This is useful since you know that if you want something to happen every n iterations and your iterator is *i* then `i % n` will be 0 every *n* iterations.

Answer (score 0):

`dumpStr += theWord + (j%4==0)? ", ": " ";`